# Select only numeric part of string only if it starts with a numeric value

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, conditional-statements

This is only giving me the last character (numeric) but I need the whole numeric string

```
SELECT substring('123 Main Street' FROM '%#"[0-9]#"%' FOR '#')
```

- Results: 3
- Expecting: 123

This gives me the same results but I need it to return a blank value:

```
SELECT substring('Main 123 Street' FROM '%#"[0-9]#"%' FOR '#')
```

- Results: 3
- Expecting:

NOTE: Postgres 7.4

Helpful Link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-matching.html

UPDATE:

```
SELECT substring('Main 123 Street' FROM '[0-9]+')
SELECT substring('123 Main Street' FROM '[0-9]+')
```

- Both now return: 123
- Still need to skip or return full string of: 'Main 123 Street'

UPDATE 2:

Almost have it:

This gives me the results I want if it doesn't start with a numeric value:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(substring('Main 123 Street' FROM '[0-9]*') || 'Main 123 Street', ''),
    substring('Main 123 Street' FROM '[0-9]*')
```

But this gives me both and I only want the second condition:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(substring('123 Main Street' FROM '[0-9]*') || '123 Main Street', ''),
    substring('123 Main Street' FROM '[0-9]*')
```

I GOT IT!!! Thanks for all who posted:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(substring(db_column FROM '[0-9]*'), db_column) != '' THEN COALESCE(substring(db_column FROM '[0-9]*'), db_column)
    ELSE db_column
END AS addsress_string
FROM db_table
```

Comment: Is this for sorting alphanumeric values that begin with numbers?

Comment: no I want to return a partial address if it starts with a numeric value else a full address

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know postgresql regex syntax, but in most regex you would write `[0-9]+`. Without the quantifier, `[0-9]` matches a single character.

Comment: Hmm lead me to different syntax, +1

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a Postgres install to test with, but something like this might work:

`SELECT substring('123 Main Street' FROM '^[0-9]+')`

That returns nothing if it doesn't start with a number. If you want to return the full string instead, this should work:

`SELECT substring('123 Main Street' FROM '^[0-9]+|.*')`

Comment: one field for both conditions in the same query?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is not yet too late to improve on rmmh's answer.

This works for me:

```
SELECT substring(column_name FROM '[0-9]+') FROM TableName;
```

In postgresql, just remove the caret for the numbers to show.

if `column_name = 'XXXX-0001'` the result will be:

```
0001
```