# select only numeric values on sql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, conditional-statements

I know there is already some of the same questions out there, but this one is confusing me.

I have this query :

```
SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(substring(location_name FROM '[0-9]+'), location_name) != '' 
    THEN COALESCE(substring(location_name FROM '[0-9]+'), location_name)
    ELSE '1'
END AS sequence
FROM LOCATION
```

What I would like to get from that query is :

1. If the `location_name` doesn't contains any numeric values, then return `1`
2. If the `location_name` contains numeric values, get only the last numeric values (after string),
   i.e. c2 carousel 10, should return only `10`
3. If the `location_name` contains only numeric values, then return `1`

But what I get is something like :

```
location_name   expected result     what I get
                                    using [0-9]         using [0-9]+
carousel 1      1                   1                   1
carousel 2      2                   2                   2
carousel 3      3                   3                   3
carousel 12     12                  1                   12
bottom banner   1                   bottom banner       bottom banner
c2 carousel 1   1                   2                   2
c2 carousel 3   3                   2                   2
59977           1                   5                   59977
```

Is it possible to do this in sql?

Comment: mysql `regex` return only `Boolean` you can't replace/filter text using regex, you should create custom string manipulation function to extract result

Comment: Looks a fair bit like http://stackoverflow.com/q/5651949/4099598.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I think it is what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (I think it will return the expected result. Else make a note what you get.)

```
SELECT location_name, 
CASE WHEN concat('',location_name * 1) = location_name THEN
     1
WHEN concat('',reverse(substring_index(reverse(location_name), ' ', 1)) * 1) = reverse(substring_index(reverse(location_name), ' ', 1)) THEN
    reverse(substring_index(reverse(location_name), ' ', 1))
ELSE
    1
END AS EXPECTED_RESULT
FROM YourTable
```

[--Quick Demo here:MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b3632/18)

It is not good when you suddenly changed the tag MYSql to PgSQL. All my works got waste.

Here is the PgSQL code:

**Create a function to check isdigit():**

```
create function isdigits(text) returns boolean as '
select $1 ~ ''^(-)?[0-9]+$'' as result
' language sql;
```

Then here is the code:

```
   SELECT location_name, 
      CASE WHEN isdigits(location_name) = true THEN 1
           WHEN isdigits(substr(location_name, length(regexp_replace(location_name, '\\s\\S+$', '')) + 2)) = true THEN 
                substr(location_name, length(regexp_replace(location_name, '\\s\\S+$', '')) + 2)::int
           ELSE 1
      END AS Result
    FROM YourTable
```

[--Quick Demo - PGSQL.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!11/82ed8/46)

Comment: Wow it's great, but why I get `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` (it's pointing to REVERSE) ?

Comment: I changed my answer for PgSQL and added link for demo too.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Create one function first which will help to check wether value is numeric or not

CREATE FUNCTION mysql_IsNumeric(val TEXT) RETURNS int(11)
RETURN val REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';

--create function that return numeric values only    
CREATE FUNCTION mysql_NumericOnly(val TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
BEGIN  
DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 0;  
IF mysql_IsNumeric(val) = 0 THEN  
IF ISNULL(val) THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;  
IF LENGTH(val) = 0 THEN RETURN ""; END IF;  
SET idx = LENGTH(val);  
WHILE idx > 0 DO   
IF strcmp(SUBSTRING(val,idx,1),'.')!=0  and mysql_IsNumeric(SUBSTRING(val,idx,1)) = 0 THEN  
SET val = REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,idx,1),"");  
SET idx = LENGTH(val)+1;  
END IF;  
SET idx = idx - 1;  
END WHILE;  
END IF;  
RETURN val;  
END;


select *,
 case when mysql_IsNumeric(location_name)=1 then 1
 case when location_name!=mysql_NumericOnly(location_name) THEN
mysql_NumericOnly(Reverse(Left(REVERSE(location_name),INSTR(REVERSE(location_name),' ')))
  else 1 end as reselut    
  from YourTable
```

Comment: The OP has switched the tags from mysql to postgresql so I don't think your answers applies anymore.